# Daily Schedule Drupal Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

I want to display a daily list of events in a block. As these events pass (throughout the day) they get removed (hidden) from the rest of the schedule. Also there are schedules everyday of the week that repeat each week. Kind of like a class schedule. I've made a start on this but want to get some expert opinions...

My present approach is to create an Event content type via CCK which has a day of the week and time field. Next I was going to make a View that brought these in based on day of the week and time of day. Does this sound right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) to unpublish the nodes at a specific time and have your view setup to only output nodes that are published. Cron must be running on your server for this to work though.

Your way is still valid but will require custom code to get it fully working. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a really clever way to approach it. Let me give it a shot.